# Linebreak in equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-breaking

I have a very simple LaTeX problem with the following LaTeX fragment:

```
The function computes:
\[
  e \leftarrow (((x||a) + (y||b)) \oplus y,\\
  r \leftarrow x + y
\]
```

The result should then be in two lines, however, using the code above write me the whole
equation in one line. Anyone an idea how I could force here a linebreak so that it looks something like:

```
The function computes:
e <--- bla bla
r <--- x + y
```

Answer (score 8):

the `\[ ... \]` method of setting a display can handle only one line.

the `amsmath` package provides a number of environments that set multiple lines in various arrangements.  see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) for details.  since you apparently want a display with no number, you need to use a starred environment; @huitseeker has already suggested

```
\begin{align*}
  e \leftarrow bla bla \\
  r \leftarrow x + y
\end{align*}
```

and that's a good answer, but he first suggested `eqnarray`, which is generally bad for mathematical documents. see [this article by lars madsen](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) for the reasons.

although no alignment is explicitly requested, it's implicit in the example shown that it is actually wanted.  without specifying an alignment point (with `&`) the lines will be aligned on the right, so if one is noticeably longer than the other, the result will not be attractive.  alignment of relations is the usual practice, so inserting `&` before `\leftarrow` in both lines is probably the best approach.

if alignment is *really* not wanted, and both lines should be centered, the `gather` environment is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **eqnarray**, as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519497/latex-linebreak-in-equations/6519506#6519506)

But the **align** environment provided by amsmath seems to be a [much](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-eqnarray) [better](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) alternative:

```
\begin{align*}
  e \leftarrow bla bla \\
  r \leftarrow x + y
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Since the OP orignally wanted to use displayed math, which doesn't have equation numbers, he'd probably be better off using \begin{align*}. And since he wasn't asking about alignment, there's no need for the ampersands.

Comment: you're right. Edited in consequence.

Comment: If you are not using alignment, it is better to use `gather` or `lgather` from mathtools