# New line in a math block

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, amsmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linebreak in equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21882/linebreak-in-equations)

I am very new to latex, its been a super frustrating I spend almost close to two hours on getting a new line inside the math block

```
\[{P(g(X) \neq Y |X = x) = 1 − P (Y = g(X)|X = x)}
{= 1 - [P(Y=1,g(X)=1|X=x) + P(Y=1,g(X)=1|X=x)]}
{= 1 − E[1_{Y =1} 1_{g(X)=1}|X = x] + E[1_{Y =0} 1{g(X)=0}|X = x]}
\]
```

Also I used underscores to show the subscript but somehow that doesn't work either.

It would be great if someone could give a pointer.

Comment: See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21882/14100) and or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3782/14100)

Comment: What doesn't work with your subscript? Does it work when you use my code below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a multiline environment from the [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package, like `align`:

```
\begin{align*}
\{P(g(X)\neq& Y \mid X=x) = 1-P(Y=g(X)\mid X=x)\}\\
\{=& 1 - [P(Y=1,g(X)=1\mid X=x)\\
&+ P(Y=1,g(X)=1\mid X=x)]\}\\
\{=& 1 - E\left[1_{Y =1} 1_{g(X)=1}\mid X = x\right]\\
&+ E\left[1_{Y =0} 1{g(X)=0}\mid X = x\right]\}
\end{align*}
```

If you don't want your equation numbered, use `align*` instead of `align`.

Instead of directly using the `amsmath` package, you can instead use [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools). It tries to fix some bugs in `amsmath` and provides additional symbols and options to change the layout of equations.

Comment: +1 but this gives an overfull hbox; can you show the OP how to fix that, perhaps break the second line into two...

Comment: And using `\bigl(`, `\bigr)` and `\bigm|` also improve the readability.

Comment: those curly brackets I have those are not to seperate a block but I really want to add them in the equation how can i get that to work.

Comment: Just escape them `\{...\}`

Comment: can you also tell me how to get rid of the equation number..? thanks bunch

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon by using, e.g., \begin{gather*} I believe.